# https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: authorization, google-oauth

### Summary

As part of learning of using Google Auth, I found that fetch("https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client") results in

```
Access to script at 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

### Expected Behavior

Headers should contain access-control-allow-origin: * like it does when fetching https://apis.google.com/js/api.js

### Actual Behavior

Response headers do not contain Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

### Steps to Reproduce

Run fetch("https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client") either in the console in devtools or in a script

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I set `crossorigin="anonymous"` for the `script` tag.

So, if I don't use CORS, everything works.